# Упрощение выражения

Tags: математика

```
 (n+1)*(n+1)!+(n+1)!-1
```

Как упростить это выражение до:

```
 (n+2)!-1
```

Прошу дать максимально развернутый ответ.

Comment: вынесите `(n+1)!` за скобки, в скобках останется ... Развернутый ответ? Ха-ха.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что он не имеет отношения к программированию/системному администрированию (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что должен же быть на ruSO какой-то минимальный уровень! Скоро будут просить ответить, сколько будет дважды два...

Comment: @Harry это будет вопрос с самой длинной дискуссией в комментариях

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Рассмотрим изначальное выражение

```
(n+1)*(n+1)! + (n+1)! - 1
```

Перепишем его следующим образом:

```
(n+1)*(n+1)! + 1 * (n+1)! - 1
```

Видим, что у первого и второго слагаемого присутствует одинаковый множитель `(n+1)!`. Используем дистрибутивность операции сложения ("вынесем за скобки"):

```
[(n+1) + 1] * (n+1)! - 1
```

Теперь используем ассоциативность операции сложения:

```
[n + (1+1)] * (n+1)! - 1 = (n+2) * (n+1)! - 1
```

Наконец, распишем факториал:

```
(n+2)*(n+1)*n*(n-1)*(n-2)*...*3*2*1 - 1
```

Легко видеть, в соответствии с определением факториала, что первое слагаемое не что иное, как факториал числа `n+2`. Таким образом, наше выражение принимает вид

```
(n+2)! - 1
```

Comment: не понимаю зачем минусовать правильный ответ

Comment: @MaxU Потому что здесь не принято решать задачи за других. А автор вопроса не приложил для решения никаких усилий, просто пожелав получить готовое. Минусы ставят в воспитательных целях.

Comment: бывают случаи когда не знаешь с чего начать... ;) В любом случае, лучше воспитывать задающих такие вопросы, а не тех кто отвечает на них...

Comment: @MaxU А есть ли смысл таких воспитывать? Они либо не понимают ("а чё такого-то???"), либо считают себя несправедливо обиженными ("чё вам, сложно што-ле???"). А люди, которые дают правильные ответы, обычно такие уроки понимают (я непонятливый!). Да и как автора вопроса воспитывать? Он пришёл, задал вопрос, получил/не получил ответ и ушёл. Получил - "Хорошо! Прокатило!", не получил - "Ну и ладно! В другом месте решат".